How can I make this code allow a user on my website to swipe left or right when on a mobile device instead of clicking to toggle through the gallery?
I have got this code where I want it for desktop. However, on mobile I need the user of the website to be able to swipe left and right on the screen without it making it so that the info button on the right bottom corner doesn't work when pressed. Solutions I have tried so far haven't worked to allow swiping, have caused the initial image not to show up, and have also obstructed the use of the info button. If it is pertinent, this site is being built on Squarespace, which at this point is probably not my favorite choice. This code is being put into a code injection on the site.
This is my code right now:
<desktopsection>
   <div id="infobutton">
    <p style="color: #654434; font-family: 'diagraph-regular'; text-align: right;">
        <a href="https://epa.squarespace.com/info" style="text-decoration: none; color: #654434; font-size: 20px; text-align: right;">Info</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <desktopfigure>
    <p id="logo"> <svg id="maindesktoplogo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="270" height="91.03725" viewBox="0 0 270 91.03725" xml:space="preserve">
        <desc>Created with Fabric.js 5.3.0</desc>
        <defs>
        </defs>
        <g transform="matrix(0.8198611373 0 0 0.8198611373 135 45.518625)" id="eGx5B61A3grPB8PTkG3e9">
          <g style="">
            <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -122.05 0)" id="AcMImDpcuKXyEip0k-1Lw">
              <path style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(101, 68, 52); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform=" translate(-183.95, -396)" d="M 150.3 346.1 L 150.3 445.90000000000003 L 217.60000000000002 445.90000000000003 L 217.60000000000002 433.70000000000005 L 163.90000000000003 433.70000000000005 L 163.90000000000003 401.20000000000005 L 206.90000000000003 401.20000000000005 L 206.90000000000003 389.30000000000007 L 163.90000000000003 389.30000000000007 L 163.90000000000003 358.30000000000007 L 217.60000000000002 358.30000000000007 L 217.60000000000002 346.1000000000001 z" stroke-linecap="round" />
            </g>
            <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -35.5 -0.05)" id="OwUpaE3KQMu1ZMxgytl_J">
              <path style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(101, 68, 52); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform=" translate(-270.5, -395.95)" d="M 277.1 390.3 C 285.90000000000003 390.3 292.5 383.5 292.5 374 C 292.5 364.7 286 358.3 277.1 358.3 L 248.10000000000002 358.3 L 248.10000000000002 390.3 L 277.1 390.3 z M 306.5 374 C 306.5 391.3 294.1 402.5 278.9 402.5 L 248.2 402.5 L 248.2 445.8 L 234.5 445.8 L 234.5 346.1 L 278.9 346.1 C 294.1 346.1 306.5 356.7 306.5 374" stroke-linecap="round" />
            </g>
            <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 32.9 0.1)" id="dwQQNLPHvIAA1jWYINEtD">
              <path style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(209,191,173); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform=" translate(-338.9, -396.1)" d="M 338.6 360.8 L 356.3 408.8 L 321.1 408.8 L 338.6 360.8 z M 333.2 346.4 L 295.8 445.79999999999995 L 307.6 445.79999999999995 L 317.40000000000003 418.99999999999994 L 360 418.99999999999994 L 369.8 445.79999999999995 L 382 445.79999999999995 L 344.4 346.4 L 333.2 346.4 z" stroke-linecap="round" />
            </g>
            <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 121.65 0)" id="eazMAliyV-nMjcLE0iIMu">
              <path style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(101, 68, 52); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform=" translate(-427.65, -396)" d="M 422.3 361.1 L 422.3 390.6 L 393.6 390.6 L 393.6 401.40000000000003 L 422.3 401.40000000000003 L 422.3 430.90000000000003 L 433.1 430.90000000000003 L 433.1 401.40000000000003 L 461.70000000000005 401.40000000000003 L 461.70000000000005 390.6 L 433.1 390.6 L 433.1 361.1 z" stroke-linecap="round" />
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg></p>
    <img id="imagecontent">
    <desktopfigcaption>
      <p id="description">description</p>
      <p id="sirname">Name</p>
      <p id="organization">orgnization</p>
    </desktopfigcaption>
  </desktopfigure>
  <button id="previous">Previous</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
</desktopsection>
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: diagraph-regular;
    scr: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/66018fd7c738c4455473aac1/t/660c276cc7e29e04bbffe27c/1712072557077/DiagraphEtc-Regular-web.woff";
  }
@media screen and (max-width:750px) {
  #previous,#next { display: none;}
}
html , body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
desktopsection {
  /* next 3 lines are optionnal here */
  /*position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;*/
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.5em 10em 1fr 1fr 10em 1.5em;
  grid-template-rows: 1.5em 1fr 1.5em;
  gap: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
desktopfigure {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2/5;
}
#previous,
#next {
  grid-row: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;/* that's enough, z-index not yet needed */
  grid-column: 1/4;/* about 13em of width according to the grid template */
  height: 80%;
  top: 1%;
}
#next {
  grid-column: 4/7;/* about 13em of width according to the grid template */
}
#infobutton {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 4/7;
  transform: translate(-100%,-0%);
  position: relative;/* that's enough, z-index not yet needed */
  margin: -2em .5em auto auto; /* no really need of transform */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #654434;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}
svg {
  height: 60px;
  width: auto;
  background: none;
  margin: 0;
}
desktopsection:before,
desktopsection:after {
  content: "";
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  height: 4px;
  background: #654434;
  margin: auto 2em 0;
}
desktopsection::after {
  grid-row: 3;
  margin: 0 2em 4em;
}
desktopfigure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; /* size it to the grid height */
}
desktopfigure img {
  grid-row: 1/4;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  object-fit: contain;/* ratio of image and ratio of view rarely matches , remove if you want image stretching*/
  object-position: center center;
}
#logo {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  position: relative;/* that's enough, z-index not yet needed */
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-left: .5em;
}
desktopfigcaption {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 1;
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.0em;
  padding: .5em 0;
  margin-left: .5em;
  max-width: 30em;
}
desktopfigcaption p {
  background: none;
  padding: 0.0em;
}


#previous:hover {
  cursor: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/66018fd7c738c4455473aac1/t/660dc8a2d1a433788c935a31/1712179362339/narrowleftsmall.png"),
    auto;
  cursor.transform: translate(-100%,-0%);
}
#next:hover {
  cursor: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/66018fd7c738c4455473aac1/t/660dc89bfa286d4dfaf6ed73/1712179355549/narrowrightsmall.png"),
    auto;
  cursor.transform: translate(-100%,-0%);
}

#organization {
  color: #d2c1af;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: diagraph-regular;
}
#sirname {
  color: #654434;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: diagraph-regular;
}
#description {
  color: #654434;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: diagraph-regular;
}
</style>
<script>
const content = [
  {
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/66018fd7c738c4455473aac1/t/660b77e58757ef3b2bbbaf65/1712027622432/Image+Filler+Horizontal.png",
    sirname: "Jane Doe",
    organization: "Adams Inc.",
    description: "This photo is a great photo showing great things"
  },
  {
    image: "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/66018fd7c738c4455473aac1/t/660b77e8666c3540780e238a/1712027624538/Image+Filler+Vertical.png", 
    sirname: "Aaron Smith",
    organization: "123 Company",
    description: "This photo is an okay photo showing mediocre things"
  },
  {
    image: "https://dummyimage.com/600x600&text=image3.jpg",
    sirname: "Jones", 
    organization: "XYZ Corp",
    description: "This is a photo"
  }
];

let currentIndex = 0;

function showContent() {
  const currentContent = content[currentIndex];

  document.getElementById("imagecontent").setAttribute('src', currentContent.image) ;
  document.getElementById("sirname").innerHTML = currentContent.sirname;
  document.getElementById("organization").innerHTML = currentContent.organization; 
  document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = currentContent.description;
}

document.getElementById("previous").addEventListener("click", () => {
  currentIndex--;
  if (currentIndex < 0) {
    currentIndex = content.length - 1; 
  }
  showContent();
});

document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", () => {
  currentIndex++;
  if (currentIndex >= content.length) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  showContent(); 
});
showContent();
</script>

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.
What I've tried:
I used this code to my  from a Medium article before deleting
function swipeDetect (desktopsection, callback) {
  var touchsurface = desktopsection,
  swipeDir,
  startX,
  startY,
  distX,
  distY,
  threshold = 50,
  restraint = 30,
  allowedTime = 150,
  elapsedTime,
  starrTime,
  handleswipe = callback || function(swipeDir) {}

touchsurface.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
  var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
  swipeDir = 'none'
  dist = 0
  startX = touchobj.pageX
  startY = touchobj.pageY
  startTime = new Date().getTime()
  e.preventDefault()
}, false)
touchsurface.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
}, false)
touchsurface.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
  var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
  distX = touchobj.pageX - startX
  distY = touchobj.PageY - startY
  elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime
  if (Math.abs(distX) >= threshold && Math.abs(distY) <= restraint){
    swipeDir = (distX < 0)? 'left' : 'right'
  handleswipe(swipeDir)
  e.preventDefault()
}, false)
}
function activateswipe ()

I couldn't figure out what should be put in the callback spot, or how to properly incorporate these instructions with the existing code. Ideally, on mobile only swipes would result in a change in the content, but that's not crucial. I basically never got this code functional.
I also tried adding this code to my , but it didn't work for swiping and it also made it so that nothing showed up until you changed content the first time:
// Detect swipe gestures
document.getElementById("desktopfigure").addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {
  touchStartX = e.touches[0].clientX;
});

document.getElementById("desktopfigure").addEventListener("touchend", (e) => {
  const touchEndX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
  const swipeDistance = touchEndX - touchStartX;

  if (swipeDistance > 0) {
    // Swipe from left to right (previous)
    currentIndex--;
    if (currentIndex < 0) {
      currentIndex = content.length - 1;
    }
  } else if (swipeDistance < 0) {
    // Swipe from right to left (next)
    currentIndex++;
    if (currentIndex >= content.length) {
      currentIndex = 0;
    }
  }

  showContent();

I've also tried a few other things that I no longer have, but that didn't seem to work properly.
